# Column vector in R and Python

Tags: python, r, vector, binary, hypothesis-test

Is it possible to create a column vector of length 500, such that first 150 rows are 1's and remaining 350 are 0's?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can use `rep` to repeat a vector.

```
vec <- rep(c(1,0), c(150, 350))
```

Comment: It worked,! Thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already, this can be done in R with

```
vec = rep(c(1,0), c(150,350))
```

In Python, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,0])
row1 = np.repeat(x, [150, 350], axis=0)
col1 = row1.reshape(-1,1)
```

If you're wanting to add this as a column in an existing dataframe, the last step is not necessary. If your dataframe is called `df`, then you can just use

```
df["New Column"] = row1
```

Comment: Thank you! The last code was also really helpful.

Comment: @RewaaK No worries. Glad to help. As part of the community at SO, please accept the answer you find most helpful by clicking on check mark on the left of the post. You can accept only one answer per post.